# Linux file locking

Tags: c, linux, windows, locking

Problem: on Linux platform create new file or overwrite an existing file so that other processes can open it for reading only. Using [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) one could do something like this:

```
CreateFile("blah.log", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ,
           NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

This call will fail to overwrite an existing file if it was opened by another process with similar flags.

How to achieve similar behavior on Linux? Assume that advisory locks are respected by all programs.

Comment: you used both the [tag:c++] and the [tag:c] tags, but the code can only be C++ **OR** C. Not both. You did not ask a single question, you just stated a problem, so... this is sadly unclear. You **must** ask a clear question, with a question mark at its end, so that we can clearly answer it.

Comment: This is a bit problematic question - you need to add *more* detail on what you intend to do. In Linux there is no proper *mandatory* file locking - the locks are advisory only - i.e. a bad program can ignore them - are these appropriate for you?

Comment: @MarcusMüller actually, the language is less relevant here - the linux system call semantics are more relevant.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala in that light, not having the language tags would be more appropriate than having both, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @quantum_well thanks for the clarifying edit, retracted my close vote ("thank you" phrases are still discouraged, we're all here to help :) )

Comment: @Marcus Müller. No. Language tag should stay. I am not asking how to do it in Python or Bash.

Comment: @quantum_well in any case neither C++ or C standard library has these calls, so you need to use non-standard ones, and the simplest are the libc/systemcall ones.

Comment: However this is a rather interesting question because Linux really doesn't have a shared-read mode with one writer either...

Comment: @quantum_well I can understand that point. However, do you want to do it in C or in C++?

Comment: @MarcusMüller so can you answer this in **any** language, when Linux really doesn't have this facility in C? - Though, I'd remove C++, because OP uses CreateFile in Windows, which is just a plain old C system call.

Comment: Yes, remove it. The API call shown as example is C, and one language is enough. Here, the Linux and Windows tags are much more relevant anyways.

Comment: In any case, there are 2 locking facilities: `flock` and record locks with `fcntl`. Neither of them directly support one writer - multiple readers. Of course if your intention is to *only* have one writer, then you just lock the writers - and the readers do not need to have any lock.

Comment: This petty talk about C/C++ tags is childish . Without C++ tag it won't show up when sorting questions according to tags. I use C++ and Windows API. Does it mean I won't be interested in similar questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `open` and the advisory `flock` locking, the writers need to hold a `LOCK_EX` exclusive lock. The readers **must not** hold *any* lock and they then might see the file being truncated abruptly.

Plain `fopen` can be used for readers. For *well-behaving* writers,

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// never truncates
int fd = open("foo.log", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY /*or O_RDWR */, 0644 /* mode */);
if (flock(fd, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) != 0) {
    perror("Locking failed - I am not an exclusive writer");
    exit(1);
}

// I hold the exclusive lock - now, truncate the file to 0 bytes
ftruncate(fd, 0);
```

(other error checking omitted for brevity)

If you wish to use `<stdio.h>` routines with the file from thereon, you can use `fdopen`:

```
// "w" will not truncate!
FILE *f = fdopen(fd, "w"); // or `r+` for O_RDWR...
```

Note that a reader **must not** set a `LOCK_SH` lock on the file, otherwise it cannot be opened by a writer.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `flock` and `lockf` functionality :)

Most of this is very much based on `man 2 flock` and `man lockf`, so I'd heartily recommend reading it.

this is from `man lockf`

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> int lockf(int fd, int cmd, off_t len);
> ```
>
> …
>
> ## DESCRIPTION
>
> Apply,  test or remove a POSIX lock on a section of an open file.  The file is specified by fd, a file descriptor open for
>   writing, the action by cmd, and the section consists of
>   byte positions pos..pos+len-1 if len is positive, and pos-len..pos-1 if len is negative, where pos is the current file
>   position, and if len is zero, the section extends from  the
>   current file position to infinity, encompassing the present and future end-of-file positions.  In all cases, the section may extend
>   past current end-of-file.
>
> On  Linux, `lockf()`  is  just  an  interface  on top of fcntl(2) locking.  Many other systems implement `lockf()` in this way,
>   but note that POSIX.1 leaves the relationship between
>   `lockf()` and `fcntl(2)` locks unspecified.  A portable application should probably avoid mixing calls to these interfaces.
>
> Valid operations are given below:
>
> - `F_LOCK` Set an exclusive lock on the specified section of the file.  If (part of) this section is already locked, the call blocks until the previous lock  is  released.   If  this section overlaps an earlier locked section, both are merged.  File locks are released as soon as the process holding the locks closes some file descriptor for the file.  A               child process does not inherit these locks.
> - `F_TLOCK` Same as `F_LOCK` but the call never blocks and returns an error instead if the file is already locked.
> - `F_ULOCK` Unlock the indicated section of the file.  This may cause a locked section to be split into two locked sections.
> - `F_TEST` Test the lock: return 0 if the specified section is unlocked or locked by this process; return `-1`, set `errno` to `EAGAIN` (`EACCES` on some other systems), if  another  process        holds a lock.

But that's only an exclusive lock, sooo not really suitable for a single writer, multi-reader case.

I'd look at unix sockets (`man unix`). They work like files or like sockets (they are sockets, but you  can use file-io functions on them), and trying to associate a socket (which can reside in the file system just like a normal file) that someone else already owns will fail.

To be honest, what you're trying to do sounds a lot like IPC (inter-process communication), which is fine – but you might want to have a look at simlper shared memory coordination! `shmget` and similar things will allow you to open things in a very file-like manner, and you can directly exchange data between processes that way, at a high performance, without incurring the penalty of writing data to disk. (you can, very similarly, do the same with memmapping actual files to memory, but that doesn't solve the locking problem).

But: these are very low-level approaches to the IPC problem. I'd recommend actually using an IPC library. There's quite a few that fit different system's needs – from MPI for large, cluster-like systems, over very nice socket-based systems, or socket-alike flexible systems (zeroMQ comes to mind).